Is there a way to physically store information in a way where it can only be read or copied once?
There was a question posed on security exchange which was basically "can physical media always be copied".  Someone brought up the idea of quantum physics here and it got me going on an idea that if the physical media could store a quantum state (non-collapsed waves, maybe stored light?!) then you should be able to make a storage media that can be read or copied but only once.  The copy could not be read.  It led me down some paths where things were going over my head so I thought I'd pose the question here.  Is there a way to physically store data in a way where it can be read or copied only once?  (conceding that once it's in digital form, that digital data can always be copied)  This would be a sort of mission impossible "this message will self destruct" type of media, but the destruction is the collapse of the wave.

I'm not aware of any way to do this.
Classical information stored in qubits can be copied as long as you know what basis it's stored in.
For example, it could be stored as horizontal-vs-vertical polarization of a photon or alternatively it could be stored as clockwise-vs-counter-clockwise polarization.
If you know the basis then there's no obstacle; it might as well be classical.
If you don't know the basis, you will risk destroying the information when you attempt to read it.
This is different from read-once; it's "read as much as you want, but might have randomized the information".
I also feel like "read-once" is inherently contradictory, since reading implies you made a copy of the information. Even if the original was destroyed, now the information is in the copy which can be copied. You probably want something more like "move-only", where the information can be moved from place to place and used in some limited way as part of computations (like "use as a key to decrypt this message") but copies can't be made. Quantum information stored in an unknown basis is sort of close to this, but in order to use it for anything you'd have to combine it with the basis information and while they're combined it's copyable.

so if I'm understanding (and a lot of this went over my head), then you couldn't store the encrypted data and the key on the same media and expect it to be non-copy-able, but you could store/copy the encrypted data, and then move the encryption key using a sort of "quantum" channel, and that's the bit that could only be read but not copied?  (so read once but only while in transit?)

@browsermator What I described is sortof just a fancy one time pad, where the pad is the measurement bases and the data is the qubits. Actually it's kinda worse than a one time pad because the information leakage is non-zero, since correct guesses give correct data; you're paying information leakage on good guesses for information destruction on bad guesses.

I guess this is the "no-cloning theory" vs. the "universal cloning machine"?  somewhere in there is "quantum error correction".   My brain hurts after trying to research this.... but it does seem like even a photon is copy-able.  Though in the analog world probably not, but close enough that probabilities would be same.

This can be done, since no-cloning theorem ensures that the quantum state cannot be perfectly copied. When the data is read (measured), the quantum superposition collapses, and the quantum state changes irreversibly.
At the moment time that quantum states stay in coherence are the problem for idea to be implemented.
Example: The one-time encryption key for the classified file, represented as a quantum state. For example, a 128-bit key encoded in qubits as a quantum superposition.
